# How can I add a certain cell to its respective column/row

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary, openpyxl

I have this Excel file that looks like this [image: excel_file].

For every name, I want to add for each group the respective cells. So I would expect a for loop that iterates by +4 rows to go through all the names.

Here's what I've done so far:

```py
import openpyxl

 doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('World Cup Bet Tournament.xlsx')

 doc_activation = doc.active

 ############################################
 """ Creating the final dictionary """
 final_dict = {}
 groups_dict = {}
 group_list = []
 ############################################

 for row_1 in range(2, 42):
     for col_1 in doc_activation.iter_cols(1, 1):
         name = col_1[row_1].value
         if name is None:
             break
         else:
             final_dict[name] = groups_dict
             for row_2 in range(1, 2):
                 for col_2 in doc_activation.iter_cols(2, 9):
                     group = col_2[row_2].value
                     groups_dict[group] = group_list


  print(final_dict)
```

and the output :

```py
{'1. Mathias L.R': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '2. Noah L.R': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '3. Jessy P.N': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '4. Enzo B.': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '5. Savio M.': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '6. Jonathan M.': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '7. Hans M.': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '8. J-E': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '9. Schadrac ': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}, '10. Mathieu G.': {'GROUP A': [], 'GROUP B': [], 'GROUP C': [], 'GROUP D': [], 'GROUP E': [], 'GROUP F': [], 'GROUP G': [], 'GROUP H': []}}
```

So for each key that represents a name, there is its value which is a dictionary and the keys of this dictionary are the name of each group. Its value is a list that would contain each country respective to the player.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to build your user's group from the values in the cell, then add that to the a group dictionary with the group name as the key e.g. GROUPA, GROUPB etc which is then added to the overall dictionary under the user's name.
See example code

```
import openpyxl


doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('World Cup Bet Tournament.xlsx')
doc_activation = doc.active

max_rows = doc_activation.max_row
max_cols = doc_activation.max_column

group, name = '', ''
groupdict, userdict = {}, {}
group_name_offset = 3

for min_row in range(2, max_rows+1, 4):
    group_name_offset -= 4
    for column_list in doc_activation.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=max_cols, min_row=min_row, max_row=min_row+3):
        group_list = []
        for count, cell in enumerate(column_list, 1):
            if count == 1:
                group = cell.offset(row=group_name_offset).value.replace(" ", "")
                if cell.column_letter == 'B':
                    name = cell.offset(column=-1).value
                    groupdict = {}
            group_list.append(cell.value)
        groupdict[group] = group_list
        userdict[name] = groupdict


### Print the User's groups
for name, groups in userdict.items():
    print(name)
    for key, teams in groups.items():
        print(f'{key} : {teams}')
```

Output

```
1. Mathias L.R
GROUPA : ['1. Pays-Bas', '2. Sénégal', '3. Équateur', '4. Qatar']
GROUPB : ['1. Angleterre', '2. Pays de Ga', '3. États-Unis', '4. Iran']
GROUPC : ['1. Argentine', '2. Pologne', '3. Mexique', '4. Arabie Saou']
GROUPD : ['1. Danemark', '2. France', '3. Tunisie', '4. Australie']
GROUPE : ['1. Espagne', '2. Allemagne', '3. Japon', '4. Costa Rica']
GROUPF : ['1. Belgique', '2. Canada', '3. Croatie', '4. Maroc']
GROUPG : ['1. Brésil', '2. Cameroun', '3. Serbie', '4. Suisse']
GROUPH : ['1. Portugal', '2. Ghana', '3. Uruguay', '4. Corée du Su']
2. Noah L.R
GROUPA : ['1. Pays-Bas', '2. Sénégal', '3. Équateur', '4. Qatar']
GROUPB : ['1. Angleterre', '2. États-Unis', '3. Pays de Ga', '4. Iran']
GROUPC : ['1. Argentine', '2. Mexique...
```